# Show QDialog With Previous Size

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a class derived from `QDialog`.  I have a single static instance that I show multiple times using `exec`.  If a user manually resizes the dialog, I would like future calls to `exec` to launch it with the previous size.

I've seen some examples where `QSettings` was used, but it seems that there should be an easier solution since I still have the same `QDialog` instance in memory (also I don't necessarily want the settings to be persistent between runs of the application).

Whats the easiest way to have a dialog instance remember the size from the last call to `exec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a static variable in your dialog class, here is a complete sample app (using 4.8.x):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDebug>

class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyDialog(QWidget *parent = 0) 
        : QDialog(parent) 
    {
        QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
        layout->addWidget(new QLabel("Test Label"));
    }

public Q_SLOTS:
    virtual int exec() { 
        resize(s_dialogSize);
        return QDialog::exec();
    }

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) { 
        Q_UNUSED(event)
        s_dialogSize = size();
    }

private:
    static QSize s_dialogSize;

};

QSize MyDialog::s_dialogSize;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyDialog dialog;
    qDebug() << dialog.exec();
    qDebug() << dialog.exec();
    qDebug() << dialog.exec();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

I've only implemented the closeEvent here, but if you want to save the size on accept/reject you need to save it to the variable in those methods as well (they are all virtual methods, and can be implemented in a similar fashion).